# Electrical induction limit

Tags: electrical-engineering

How much current can a metal object "hold" using electrical induction? For example a 1 kg ball of iron.

Lets say i start to charge the item negatively. 
I suppose its up to the mass and the kind of metal. But how can you induce more and more current in there and is there a limit on how much it can take? If there is one, why there is a limit what will happen if i try to induce more? Having in mind ofcourse that this metal object is in a complete insulating environment.

Ps: how to induce more current? Just have some current on the nearby object and wait or always increase the amount of current?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, how much *charge* can an electrode hold, the limit is not typically due to the electrode itself, but due to the surrounding dielectric and other nearby conductive material. The charge on the electrode creates an electric field around it. As the charge increases, at some point the electric field strength becomes high enough to *break down* the surrounding dielectric, and charge will be conducted away from the electrode.

If you mean how much current can a conductor *carry*, the limit typically depends on how the conductor is cooled. The current through the conductor heats the conductor (due to *joule heating*). The temperature rise depends on the balance between this heating and cooling due to conduction and convection away from the conductor. When the temperature rises too much, the conductor melts and doesn't maintain its shape, which typically breaks the circuit.

Comment: So if theoretically you use a very big amount of insulation and dielectric around the charged metal object and cool the surroundings then you can increase the charge right? There is no other variable to how much charge the object can hold? Thanks again

Comment: @Savroy, typically, vacuum has better breakdown characteristics than a solid dielectric, so adding insulation will make things worse. And, like I said in my answer, the cooling has to do with the current flowing through the conductor, not the charge stored on it.